# Проблемы с number_format

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Возникла проблема с применением `number_format`. Проблема возникает в дальнейшем использовании в javascript отформатированного числа. Вот код:

html+php

```
<a class="click">click</a>
  <p class="summ">
    <?php 
      $result =10000;
      $result = number_format(result, 2, '.', ' ');
      echo $result;
    ?>
   </p>
  <p class="result"></p>
```

javascript(jQuery)

```
jQuery(".click").click(function(){
  var price = jQuery('.summ').html();
  prise=price+1;
  jQuery('.result').html(prise);
});
```

В результате в `<p class="result">` вываливается ответ 11. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так получаеться и как устранить проблему.

Comment: http://tsya.ru

Comment: спасибо. У меня проблема с орфоргафией всегда была :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
price = parseFloat( price.split(' ').join('') ); // убрали пробелы-разделители разрядов числа, преобразовали в Float
price = price + 1;  // из 10 000 получили 10001
```

Т.к. php, судя по функции number_format(), может вернуть дробное число с 2 десятичными знаками на конце - в javascript лучше использовать parseFloat вместо parseInt, чтобы эти десятичные части числа не потерялись.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в этом куске кода:

```
var price = jQuery('.summ').html();
prise=price+1;
```

Метод html() возвращает строку, а не число. И получается, что ты пытаешься сложить строку с числом, а не число с числом. Нужно всего-то использовать parseInt().

```
var price = jQuery('.summ').html();
prise=parseInt(price)+1;
```

Comment: Не ужели же вы думаете что строка 10000 плюс 1 будет 11, а на 100001? Или сразу не понятно что код написан для примера в оригилале конечно же используеться parseInt.

Comment: Неужели в русском языке есть слово "ужели"?

Php вам возвращает не 10000, а 10 000. 

Преобразование строки в число из 10 000 делает 10, т.к. выкидывает весь остаток строки, наткнувшись на пробел.

Javascript складывает 10 и 1 и получается 11.

Comment: Ну это как то понятно, а вот как это можно поправить вот вчем вопрос. Мне пришлось создавать соседний <imput type="hidden" и внего передавать не форматированные данные. И уже брать от туда данные. Вот и думаю как то проще можно это решить?

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = parseInt($('.summ').html().match(/[0-9]/g).join(''));
```

Фильтруем цифры в строке и конвертируем в тип number.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="click">click</a>
  <p class="summ">
    <?php 
      $result =10000;
      $result = number_format(result, 2, '.', ' ');
      echo $result;
    ?>
   </p>
  <p class="result"></p>
```

1 ошибка в

> $result = number_format(result, 2,
> '.', ' ');

правильный вариант:

> $result = number_format($result, 2,
> '.', ' ');

```
jQuery(".click").click(function(){
  var price = jQuery('.summ').html();
  prise=price+1;
  jQuery('.result').html(prise);
});
```

2 ошибка:
 попробуйте так:

> jQuery(".click").click(function(){
> var price = jQuery('.summ').text();
> prise=price+1;
> jQuery('.result').text(prise); });

старайтесь использовать text, а не html т.к. будут проблемы с безопасностью!

Comment: Насчет 1 ошибки, писал чуть высше это не сосвсем живой код, поэтому видимо опечатки потому как писал быстро. Насчет второй спасибо учту но это все равно не меняет сути дела. :)